# Audio Player in PHP

Tags: php, audio, media-player

i am creating a site for Audio songs shopping cart. File Formats i used in this site are MP3 and WMA only. I want a default player code which support all browsers and Also All OS. I try both  and . Sometime it needs to some plugins like quicktime. Mostly i face this problem in Linux and Windows. In such case User have to install those plugin. I want to create a standard player without any plugins. Is any possible to do? Please suggest.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Soundmanager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/), which is based on Flash, works quite well.

Comment: Even better: it is based on HTML5 and/or Flash, so the range of supported devices is much wider - when using appropriate codecs. Alas, MP3s are only supported through Flash :(